# Duplicate Content Database driven Website

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, database

I have a listing based website similar to yelp. We have different pages for a listing for example basic information, photos, reviews, google map address etc. Now most content on this page is similar. Take for example [Information](http://www.revoba.com/dubai/restaurants-cafe/texas-roadhouse-downtown-dubai/) and [Photos](http://www.revoba.com/dubai/restaurants-cafe/texas-roadhouse-downtown-dubai/photos/). These pages are significantly similar and when I use http://www.webconfs.com/similar-page-checker.php as expected I see a 64% content match.

However another similar website called zomato has the same structure in terms of pages. Their pages [Link 1 on Zomato](https://www.zomato.com/dubai/claw-bbq-crabshack-grill-downtown-dubai/menu#tabtop)  and [Link 2 on zomato](https://www.zomato.com/dubai/claw-bbq-crabshack-grill-downtown-dubai/photos#tabtop) are also very much similar. Infact when we do a match of the view source, they are almost similar just like our website. However the similar website check shows 0% similar content when compared.

Can someone advise why is this difference? Also what can be done in our case to avoid duplicate content since having similar pages is inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

> However the similar website check shows 0% similar content when [the Zomato pages are] compared. Can someone advise why is this difference?

A man shouldn't blame his tools, but I think the problem in this case is with the "tool". It looks like the "similar page checker" is simply failing (quietly) on the Zomato links. If you notice on the results page it has prefixed "http://" onto the URLs, which are already prefixed with the HTTPS protocol ("https://")! It looks like it is simply unable to handle "https://" URLs!?

But also, if you specify those URLs as "http://" (the site itself redirects to https) then that tool returns "100% similar" - I would guess it's not following redirects (and is incorrectly comparing the initial "redirect" response, which is going to be *very similar*), so is also "failing" (quietly).

> Also what can be done in our case to avoid duplicate content since having similar pages is inevitable.

Google doesn't simply do a straight text comparison between pages. It is a bit cleverer than that. I expect it is more concerned about the actual page "content". Repeating page elements such as headers, footers and navigation are not going to count so much, providing you have other "content" on the page.

But also note that "duplicate content" is not necessarily a penalty; if that is what you are implying. It simply means that if Google decides that two pages are duplicate then only one is likely to be returned in the SERPs.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at all 4 links; yours are very similar because of your sites template. Their site however is not similar because their is more content than template.  Consider scaling down your template or add more relevant content.